# Display value in select tag instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown list, which should display value instead of text.

But, when I click the dropdown, the option should display the text instead of value.

I have added an example here, but it is not working as expected:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <select>
  <option name="One" value="1">One</option>
  <option name="Two" value="2">Two</option>
  <option name="Three" value="3">Three</option>
  <option name="Four" value="4">Four</option>
 </select>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').click(function() {
      $('select :selected').text($('select :selected').val());
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a picture of the example.

[image: example]

Comment: it should be `$(this).find('option:selected').val()`

Comment: It should be mousedown, not click, but there's no way you'll have "1" and "one" at the same time with the standard widget. You need to write your own widget or hide part of the standard one (for example with a div)

Comment: It isn't possible to create something as per your picture using a native `<select>`. You'd need a plugin that uses CSS/Script to _emulate_ a dropdown effect. Maybe just put "1 (One)" as the text in the first place? Also `<option>` tags don't have a "name" attribute. That belongs on the `<select>` and is used as the name of the field when submitting the form to the server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thank you for your correction.

Comment: @Raffel no worries :)

Comment: @DenysSéguret i used the click event because i make this website for mobile and desktop too. but, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your answer. i'll try it later.

Comment: Great its working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select option[value="+$('select option:selected').val()+"]").css({"background-color":"#0000ff","color":"#fff"});
    $('select').change(function() {
     $('select option')[0].value=$('select option:selected').val();
     $('select option')[0].innerHTML=$('select option:selected').val();
     $("select").val($('select option:selected').val());
     $("select option").css({"background-color":"","color":""});
     $("select option[value="+$('select option:selected').val()+"]").css({"background-color":"#0000ff","color":"#fff"});
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select>
  <option name="One" value="1" style="display:none">1</option>
  <option name="One" value="1">One</option>
  <option name="Two" value="2">Two</option>
  <option name="Three" value="3">Three</option>
  <option name="Four" value="4">Four</option>
 </select>
```

I have created an extra option which will be display none. Now whenever user will change any option I will change the value and text of the 1st element which is not displaying and Then setting the first value to be selected

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I clicked the box it doesn't select the current option

Comment: Yeah because If I will select that value then above value will be change

Comment: You can create custom drop down using UL and LI and show whatever you want to do

Comment: I think you should create custom

Comment: Well Now try again

Comment: Change Your color accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your updates.. but sorry, it doesn't work well on mobile.

Comment: Then only one option create custom using UL and LI

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, I suggest using dropdown-menu and add a click listener on each dropdown item to change the dropdown-menu text.

this is a sample code I use for filtering table and show icon of filter type instead of value text.

```
<div class="btn-group flex-fill" dir="ltr">
<input type="text" enterkeyhint="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="filter_title" autocomplete="off" onclick="$(this).val('')">
<button class="btn border dropdown-toggle p-1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span id="ifilter_title"></span>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu text-center">
    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="$('#ifilter_title').text('1');"><span>One</span></a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="$('#ifilter_title').text('2');"><span>Two</span></a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="$('#ifilter_title').text('3');"><span>Three</span></a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="$('#ifilter_title').text('4');"><span>Four</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do for a native select element, try adding label property in your option, `<option value="1" label="1" selected>One</option>`